# Zend Framework Error on _initAutoload() functon

Tags: zend-framework

I am learning Zend framework myself. I am facing error on initial installation of zend framework.

For start I created a controller for books `BooksController.php`

```
<?php

class BooksController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function listAction()
    {
        echo "hi";
        $bookTBL = new Model_Books();
    }

}
```

I created Books model on file `Books.php`

```
<?php

class Model_Books extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    protected $_name = 'books';
}
```

To load Model_Books model I created `_initAutoload()` function at `Bootstrap.php`

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    protected function _initAutoload() {
        $modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
                            'namespace' => '',
                            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH
                        ));

        return $modelLoader;                
    }

}
```

I have also configured Database on `application.ini`

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

database.adapter         = mysql
database.params.host     = localhost
database.params.username = root
database.params.password = 123456
database.params.dbname   = zftutorial

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

After these all coding when I tried to open http://localhost/zftutorial/public/books/list url in browser it is giving me `Application error`.

Please guide me where I have mistaken.

Comment: Try setting: `resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions` to 1, it will give you exception stack and message.

Comment: @DanielGadawski After that it is showing me error It is showing error ` Message: No adapter found for Model_Books `. what that means

Comment: There are two things wrong in this picture:
1. Zend Framework 1.*.* is or will be depricated in month or two!
2. Please dont use MySql as Adapter it is depricated from php5.4 and it is unsafe for use. Please use PDO or mysqli

And error:
In your public/index.php add ini_set("display_errors",1); and you will se php exception if it is there if it is not displayed try as  @DanielGadawski said

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure in which mode you are working if you dont know than simply specify it in your `.htaccess` like this:

Your file path: `zftutorial/public/.htaccess`

Add this line in it.

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This will make sure that you are in `development` mode.

Remove this from your `production` mode for now:

```
database.adapter         = mysql
database.params.host     = localhost
database.params.username = root
database.params.password = 123456
database.params.dbname   = zftutorial
```

and add this in your `development` mode:

```
[development : production]
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "123456"
resources.db.params.dbname = "zftutorial"
```

This might solve your issue.